# Output of JSON addon is blank when embedded in another template

Tags: json

When using this [json addon](https://github.com/rsanchez/json) in a template, it outputs just fine. However, when I try to call that template using embed into another template, it ends up as

```
'[]'
```

My setup is similar to this:

```
template/json
{exp:json:entries channel="resources"...}

template/main
{exp:channel:entries}
...stuff
{embed="template/json"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Do you need to embed the entry ID or anything like that?

Comment: I've tested with your example and it works fine for me, though I'm assuming it's just a typo in your code example where you have a `:` instead of a `=` in the `embed` tag?

Comment: Typo was in my example, but my template code is fine. After a little bit more testing, it embeds and renders correctly in other templates, but not the one I need it to render on. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

Found out through some more testing that it is a strange bug with how templates are being routed.

The json outputs fine on a page when seeing the rendered directly from the template.

However, when the page rendered through a page, this is when it fails.

Could not find a fix so far, but a workaround so far is to ajax in the json instead of directly embedding it on a page.

Answer (score 1):

Probably need a dynamic="no" on your json tag.